# Properties of Integrals: MVT, Change of Variable, Taylor's Expansion

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, proof-verification

Prove that $$\int_a^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx = \int_1^\frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx $$ for all $a>0$ without using the antiderivative of the integrand.

---

**Change of Variables Formula**:

Let $\varphi:[a,b] \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable and $f:[a,b] \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $\varphi([a,b]) = [c,d]$, $\varphi(a)=c$ , $\varphi(b)=d$.  Then

$\int_c^d f(x)dx = \int_a^b f(t)\varphi(t) dt$

**Calculus 2 u-substitution**

Comment: By means of what substitution could $a$ become $1/a$?

Comment: Looked at maby using the composition of the f-function?

Comment: Woodface, I believe that is what I want to do.

Comment: Probably no one would have voted to close this if it had not been phrased in a manner suitable for assigning homework.

Comment: And once again we see the stupidity of the way closures of questions are done on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Letting $x = 1/t$, we have $dx = -(1/t^2)\, dt$, and thus

$$\int_a^1 \frac{1}{1 + x^2}\, dx = \int_{1/a}^1 \frac{1}{1 + t^{-2}} (-t^{-2})\, dt = \int_1^{1/a} \frac{1}{t^2 + 1}\, dt.$$

Comment: I'm a little confused here, and how you swihched things around?

Comment: It would help if you were more specific. I did a $t$-substitution $t = 1/x$, which is equivalent to $x = 1/t$.